# Oracle PL/SQL trigger won't allow to select records from same table and update into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have condition where i need to update table x1 with the value of e1,e2,and e3. Assume e1 is primary key. When data gets modified on X2, I need to pull max of e2 and max of e3 to update the table X1. I wrote trigger like this however getting mutating table error. I don't want to use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION. Your help would be appriciated.

```
    create or replace TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_ON_X2
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON X2
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  cnt NUMBER;
  E1 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE);
  E2 NUMBER(3,0);
  E3 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT FROM X1 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1;
    IF(CNT =0)THEN
       INSERT INTO X1 (E1, E2, E3)  VALUES(:NEW.E1,:NEW.E2,:NEW.E3);
    ELSE  
        SELECT E1,E2,E3 INTO E1,  E2, E3 FROM X1 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1;
        IF(:NEW.E1 > E1) THEN
            E1 := :NEW.E1;
        END IF;
        IF(:NEW.E2 > E2) THEN
            E2 := :NEW.E2;
        END IF;
        IF(:NEW.E3 > E3) THEN
            E3 := :NEW.E3;
        END IF;
        UPDATE X1 SET E1 = E1, E2 = E2, E3 = E3 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1;
    END IF;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT FROM X2 WHERE CONTRACTORSOIDENTIFIER = :NEW.CONTRACTORSOIDENTIFIER;
    IF(CNT != 0)THEN
        SELECT E1,MAX(E2),MAX(E3) INTO E1,  E2, E3 FROM X2 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1 GROUP BY X2.E1;
        IF(:NEW.E1 > E1) THEN
            E1 := :NEW.E1;
        END IF;
        IF(:NEW.E2 > E2) THEN
            E2 := :NEW.E2;
        END IF;
        IF(:NEW.E3 > E3) THEN
            E3 := :NEW.E3;
        END IF;
        UPDATE X1 SET E1 = E1, E2 = E2, E3 = E3 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1;
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM X1 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want to update X2 when X1 is modified, but your trigger is for changes to X2 and updates X1.

Comment: Sorry my bad. It is exactly what you understood. I will change it in description

Comment: What is this meant to do? `UPDATE X1 SET E1 = E1, E2 = E2, E3 = E3 WHERE E1 = :NEW.E1;` E1 is already E1, etc.

Comment: Also your caps lock is on ;)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson It is meant to update the row. Assume before triggrer x1 has (1,1,1) for e1,e2,e3. Now tabel x2 updated with (1,2,3) then x1 should be updated as (1,2,3). So if you check if block above update, It is taking greater value and put it in respective variables and then updates x1

Comment: I think the problem is in the deleting block because you are querying the same table that owns the trigger (x2). Also, when deleting :new are going to be null.

Comment: Yes only delete blocks giving mutable error. Insert and update is good.

Comment: Could you change the delete portion to push an event into a queue and perform the update afterwards?

Comment: You don't also have a trigger on X1, do you?

Comment: @user3533451 Within SQL statements in PL/SQL code, column names take precedence over PL/SQL variables with the same name. So `set e1 = e1` means set the column `e1` to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there can be many rows per e1 in x2. And for each e1 that exists in x2 there exists one row in x1. The x1 row contains the maximum values for e2 and e3 per e1.

Your `INSERTING OR UPDATING` part looks okay, apart from naming your variables identical to your columns. As William Robertson already pointed out in the request comments, `SET E1 = E1` just means keep the value as is. The DBMS doesn't guess that the second E1 is supposed to be the other E1. It is common to precede variables with v_ to make them distinct from column names.

Your `DELETING` has a main issue. The problem is that by deleting an x2 row, the x1 maximums must be evaluated anew for the e1. This means that we must select from x2 while the table is in the process of changing. (As a delete statement can affect more than one row, `AFTER ROW` does not necessarily mean `AFTER STATEMENT`, so we may be in the middle of changes and can not deterministicly say what's yet in the table and what not.)

The solution to this is a compound trigger. This trigger type combines before/after row and before/after statement. So you can look at the rows, see which e1 are affected and then after all the rows processing you update x1 for all affected e1.

Here is a simple trigger (that certainly leaves room for optimization :-)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_x1_on_x2
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON x2
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  v_array SYS.ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT := SYS.ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT();

  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    -- Add e1 to the array for a later insert/update/delete in x1
    v_array.EXTEND;
    v_array(v_array.COUNT) := COALESCE(:new.e1, :old.e1);
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    -- Delete rows from x1 where the e1 no longer exists in x2
    DELETE FROM x1
    WHERE e1 IN (select * from table(v_array))
    AND e1 NOT IN (select e1 from x2);

    -- Insert/update x1 rows with the new maximums found in x2
    MERGE INTO x1
    USING
    (
      SELECT e1, MAX(e2) AS max_e2, MAX(e3) AS max_e3
      FROM x2
      WHERE e1 IN (select * from table(v_array))
      GROUP BY e1
    ) src ON (src.e1 = x1.e1)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET e2 = src.max_e2, e3 = src.max_e3
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (e1, e2, e3) VALUES (src.e1, src.max_e2, src.max_e3)
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END tr_update_x1_on_x2;
```